# Embed Approver name to the current item word document

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Good Day,

I have a document library that has a workflow running with two approvals. I want the names of the "First Approver" and "Second Approver" to be written in the current item word document.

How can i achieve this?

Many Thanks
Mzizi

Comment: I don't think you can do this out of the box, you would have to create something in Visual Studio, I believe.

Comment: @RafaelBonametti, can't I even do it in SharePoint Designer?

Comment: Inside the .doc file? I don't know of any way of doing that. SharePoint Designer is mainly to edit parts of SharePoint itself.

Comment: I actually just found this, it might help you: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/brenclarke/2009/04/15/automatically-create-word-documents-which-include-list-fields/

Comment: Yes inside the .doc file. Thanks Rafael, i saw this article but unfortunately it didn't help.